# Persistent Sign In Using AWS with Xamarin

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I am using the AWSSDK Nuget packages in my Xamarin mobile app (c#). I authenticate the user and get back AccessToken, RefreshToken, IdToken, etc.. but if the user closes the app without signing out, how can I retrieve those tokens?

The AWS docs for Xamarin seem to be pretty much non-existent. I have been using [the docs for .Net](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/aws-sdk-net-v3-dg.pdf) as a resource, but it doesn't mention anything about persistent sign ins.

Do I need to take it upon myself to store the tokens on the device locally? If so, what are the best practices for this?

Comment: Short answer, Yes, you need to save the tokens. As far as how, what Xamarin platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting both Android and iOS. (Using native, not Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: Use the `Keychain` on iOS and a `KeyStore` on Android. As a *quick* reference, you can look how `Xaramin.Auth` does it for each platform if you want to just grab the source (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth#42-store-the-account) or just use the whole package directly and let the linker strip out the un-used portions... not endorsing that entire package as I have "issues" with how its security is done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Xamarin.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth). It has the code to securely store the tokens on the client device. As long as the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth) is available, you can either use the library as a cross-platform account store or just grab the code to store data for each platform:

[iOS Account Store](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/source/Xamarin.Auth.XamarinIOS/AccountStore)

[Android Account Store](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/source/Xamarin.Auth.XamarinAndroid/AccountStore)

[WinRT Account Store](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/source/Xamarin.Auth.WinRTWindows81/AccountStore)

[UWP Account Store](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/source/Xamarin.Auth.UniversalWindowsPlatform)

The library is regularly updated and maintained. Consider joining the [Xamarin Slack chat](https://xamarinchat.slack.com) for quick technical answers.